# Replace the comma with semicolon in array

Tags: javascript

I have this object
I have an object with an array with different values

```
var myObj = {
            "number": 10,
            "general": "general",
            "array": [{
                "num1": 11,
                "text": "text1",
            }, {
                "num2": 1,
                "text": "text2",
            }, {
                "num3": 3,
                "text": "text3",

            } ]
        };
```

I take back the result text1,text2,text3 using this

```
var result = myObj.array.map(function (item) {
  return item.text;
});
```

How can I take back this result text1;text2;text3

Comment: You want to get a string with `text1;text2;text3`? If so, as `result` is an array, use `result.join(';')` to get that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment, you're not really getting them with commas - that's just how your console is displaying an array of values. To return what you want (the items delimited by a semicolon, just use the Array.join function.

```
var result = myObj.array.map(function (item) {
  return item.text;
}).join(";");
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join);

> The join() method joins all elements of an array into a string.
>
> ### Syntax
>
> str = arr.join([separator = ','])
>
> ### Parameters
>
> separator - Optional. Specifies a string to separate each element of the
>   array. The separator is converted to a string if necessary. If
>   omitted, the array elements are separated with a comma. If separator
>   is an empty string, all elements are joined without any characters in
>   between them.

Answer (score 3):

Join them with `join`:

```
var result = myObj.array.map(function (item) {
    return item.text;
}).join(';');
```

Comment: @Ster32 Sorry, I don't understand your question.